# Writing of output into a file

Tags: python, file-io

Am trying to create a worldlist with a limited number of duplicate peer line when a character can only repeat not more than 3 time's in a line.

> Accepted: 10101075

> Unacceptable: 11101110

Then I came across the below python script that did exactly what I want

```
filename='/root/out.txt'
def StringContainsNoMoreThanNOccurancesOfSameCharacter(s, N):
    H={}
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        c=s[i]
        if c in H:
            H[c]+=1
            if(H[c]==N+1): return False
        else:
            H[c]=1
    return True

with open(filename) as file:
     for line in file:
         line=line.strip()
         if(StringContainsNoMoreThanNOccurancesOfSameCharacter(line, 3)): print (line)
```

Need help in editing the script to write the output into a **.txt** file.

Answer (score 0):

Just open both input and output files, and redirect print:

```
with open(filename) as file, open('accept3.txt', 'w') as outFyle:
     for line in file:
         line=line.strip()
         if(StringContainsNoMoreThanNOccurancesOfSameCharacter(line, 3)):
             print(line, file=outFyle)
```